# python - multiple strings in word

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to do this -

```
word = 'hello'

if 'a' or 'c' in word:
    continue
elif 'e' in word:
    continue
else:
    continue
```

It only works if I don't have the or.  The string is a single word.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: See the answer below I accepted.  I needed to know if both letters were in a word to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `if 'a' or 'c' in word:` with `if 'a' in word or 'c' in word`. Generally you'll have to provide that `in word` for each character you are testing. You could also use `any`, but since your `if` is simple, you can just use the format above.

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
if 'a' or 'c' in word:
    continue
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if ('a') or ('c' in word):
    continue
```

And `'a'` is always `True` in boolean context, therefore `continue` is always performed due to short-circuiting.

Solution:

```
if any(c in word for c in ('a', 'c')):
    continue
```

Comment: `continue` cannot be used without loop

Comment: @haifzhan "It only works if I don't have the or." - I assumed it's an extract of full script, where `continue` makes sense.

Comment: Huh.  Amazing the holes in your knowledge you find when you read questions.  I've never run across `any` in use before and only vaguely remember learning about it.

Answer (score 1):

1)
It should be `if 'a' in word or 'c' in word:`

2) `continue` will raise `SyntaxError`, because you didnt use it in loop. If you dont do anything, you can use `pass` other than `continue`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `any` built-in function like so:

```
any(i in ('a', 'c') for i in word)
```